# How to extract the most common words in a dataset (multiple rows) in R?

Tags: r

I'm using a data set where there are 2 columns: 'type' and 'posts'. Under 'type' there are 16 different personality types (multiple entries, there are ~8000 rows), and the 'posts' contain different words. I wish to be able to choose one 'type' and be able to find the most commonly used words from all the entries of this specific 'type'.

I've been trying to create separate data frames with only one 'type' and all of its 'posts' but I am not sure where to go from here.

For reference, I am aiming to create a final summary table of only one of each of the 16 'type's and most common words from 'posts'.

For the data set: https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/mbti-type

When using:

```
most_common_words <- mbti_train %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(posts, sep = "\\s+") %>%
  group_by(type) %>% 
  count(type, posts) %>%
  top_n(20, n)
```

This is outputted:

```
    type    posts   n
1   ENFJ    dont    1106
2   ENFJ    feel    1104
3   ENFJ    friend  713
4   ENFJ    get     924
5   ENFJ    go      714
6   ENFJ    I'm     2003
7   ENFJ    I've    689
8   ENFJ    know    1001
9   ENFJ    like    1762
10  ENFJ    love    775
11  ENFJ    make    664
12  ENFJ    one     875
13  ENFJ    peopl   1183
14  ENFJ    person  698
15  ENFJ    realli  887
16  ENFJ    thing   816
17  ENFJ    think   1400
18  ENFJ    time    762
19  ENFJ    want    632
20  ENFJ    would   779
21  ENFP    dont    3847
22  ENFP    feel    3183
23  ENFP    friend  2290
24  ENFP    get     3229
25  ENFP    go      2479
26  ENFP    I'm     6779
27  ENFP    I've    2324
28  ENFP    know    3325
29  ENFP    like    6478
30  ENFP    love    2857
31  ENFP    make    2239
32  ENFP    one     3175
33  ENFP    peopl   3675
34  ENFP    realli  3074
35  ENFP    say     2205
36  ENFP    thing   2874
37  ENFP    think   4613
38  ENFP    time    2672
39  ENFP    want    2121
40  ENFP    would   2602
```

As you can see, the `posts` are the same 20 words even though the `type` is different.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(mbti_train))` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Okay! Also, I used your Mode function and the tables now look like they produce the words, however, there are a LOT of them. Is there a way to only output ~20 words?

Comment: Yes, you had to use the `Mode` function defined here in my answer. Do you have long sentences in `posts`? Do you want to break it down into words first and then get the one with most common word?

Comment: @RonakShah I believe that they may be in a format of very long sentences. There are no commas separating the words at all. In that case, I do believe that I'd like to break it into words first and then get the top 20 common words.... thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you try `mbti_train %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(posts, sep = "\\s+") %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(posts = Mode(posts))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah this works, but there is only one word in the 'posts' column. I'd like there to be ~20 words in each row if that's possible?

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split the sentences into word using `separate_rows`, `count` their occurrences and for each `type` select top 20 words using `top_n`.

```
library(dplyr)

mbti_train %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(posts, sep = "\\s+") %>%
  count(type, posts) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  top_n(20, n)
```